# Vue-chartjs: Re-render a chart even if data hasn't changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I have a component with two charts which I show on the button click. I use the same component of a chart but I give different `chartData` to it through two different getters. The chart looks like this:

```
<script>
import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';

export default {
extends: Bar,
mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
props: ['chartData', 'options'],
mounted() {
   this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  },
};
</script>
```

I know that `reactiveProp` renders a new chart if data has changed (and initialises nice animation). But currently two getters give the same data for `this.chartData` so when I try to switch the chart, it stays the same. Is there any way to update or destroy data so the chart will be re-rendered, even if it gets the same data from another getter? For some reasons, methods like update(), destroy(), clear() didn't work out but maybe I used them in the wrong place.

Here's my page with the chart:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <button @click="showAll = false">
          Show old users
  </button>
  <button @click="showAll = true">
          Show all users
  </button>
  <chart v-if="isChartData === true && showAll === false" :options="options" :chart-data="setDataOld" />
  <chart v-if="isChartData === true && showAll === true" :options="options" :chart-data="setData" />
 <div>
<template>
```

Comment: Use a [key](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key).

Comment: Thanks. I used this and now my chart is re-rendered every time I click the button but the console says:  Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.
I added key like this:
`<chart v-if="isChartData === true && showAll === false" :options="options" :chart-data="setDataOld" :key="setDataOld" />`

Comment: I think you want `:key="'setDataOld'"`. If you want to use an explicit string you need to use single quotes inside double quotes (or vice versa). Basically, you don't want your key to be an object, you want it to be some primitive value, and it doesn't have to be any *specific* value, it just needs to be different for chart one and chart two. Really, you could just use `:key="1"` and `:key="2"` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Note the [keys](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key).

```
<chart :key="1" v-if="isChartData === true && showAll === false" :options="options" :chart-data="setDataOld" />
<chart :key="2" v-if="isChartData === true && showAll === true" :options="options" :chart-data="setData" />
```

Essentially you want to be able to give Vue a hint about what differentiates the two charts so it knows explicitly which one to render instead of making use of its default component re-use strategy.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution is so simple, yet I would never think to use `key` apart from the case when you need to male a list with `v-for`. Now everything works fine.